# Scala:No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Thing]: can not instantiate from JSON object

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have tried to test the following code to reading Json , but it false.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator; 
import java.sql.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


@JsonCreator
case class JsonLong{
  @JsonProperty("fdn") var fdn: String = null
  @JsonProperty("type") var tpy: String= null
  @JsonProperty("vid") var vid: String = null
  @JsonProperty("version") var version: String = null
  @JsonProperty("device_id") var device_id: String = null
  @JsonProperty("ip") var ip: String = null
  @JsonProperty("timestamp") var timestamp: Long = 0L
}


def jsonString(logjson:String):JsonLong ={
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val record = mapper.readValue(logjson, classOf[JsonLong])
    record
  }


val jsoninput = "{\"fdn\":\"FDNB2023750\",\"type\":\"0\",\"vid\":\"2246195\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"device_id\":\"HM+NOTE+1TD_0c-1d-af-7e-1e-a3_865813020970745\",\"ip\":\"106.118.164.215\",\"timestamp\":1463847764}"


val jsonRDD =   jsonString(jsoninput)
```

Here is the Json I want to read:
"{\"fdn\":\"FDNB2023750\",\"type\":\"0\",\"vid\":\"2246195\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"device_id\":\"HM+NOTE+1TD_0c-1d-af-7e-1e-a3_865813020970745\",\"ip\":\"106.118.164.215\",\"timestamp\":1463847764}"

I get the following response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9kW.png)

I know 'type' is a keyword in Scala. So, I tried using @JsonProperty.It's that my code is right ? OR there are any other problems with class JsonLong?

Comment: I do not have a complete answer but you probably have 2 problems here. First, the json you gave as an example contains the key "ttype" instead if "type", so jackson cannot find the constructor. Secondly, `my_type` is a scala Option. I do not known if Jackson can handle those as it is a java library.

Comment: sorry, here is no "ttype", I renamed "type" to "ttpye" just for test~~I change "my_type" to other names.It still wrong~~                                                        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class $line45.$read$$iwC$$iwC$JsonLong]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: Does Jackson know how to instantiate an `Option[String]`?

Comment: As a side note, `my_type: Option[String] = null` is probably not a good idea anyway, since it sort of defeats the purpose of using `Option`

Comment: But I think that is not the problem~~I try to printSchema, It shows root
 |-- log_version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- log_ip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- log_from: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SDK: string (nullable = true)
 |-- action_time: date (nullable = true)
 |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- post_code: struct (nullable = true)
post_code as a struct type, but not know what in it~~

Answer (score 1):

I find one way to deal with this log. But not use jackson,use json4s to catch the key value.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats 

case class JsonLong(
  var fdn: String=null,
  var `type`: String=null, 
  var vid: String=null,
  var version: String=null,
  var device_id: String=null,
  var ip: String=null,
  var timestamp: Long=0L
)

val jsoninput = "{\"fdn\":\"FDNB2023750\",\"type\":\"0\",\"vid\":\"2246195\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"device_id\":\"HM+NOTE+1TD_0c-1d-af-7e-1e-a3_865813020970745\",\"ip\":\"106.118.164.215\",\"timestamp\":1463847764}"
val jsontest = parse(jsoninput, useBigDecimalForDouble = true)
    jsontest.extract[JsonLong]
```

Comment: I heard that no argument case class should actually be a case object. The problem is that you need a default constructor, but how do you bind the request to the members, right? I'm trying to figure that out right now, but I'd like to stick to Jackson.